# Recover file from partition after writing on it

Tags: linux, partition, data-recovery

I really did a big mistake. I have a partition sda6 for backup, when writing the iso to a pendrive, instead of typing sdb6, i've typed sda6, is there any way to get back the files

Comment: What are the sizes of the iso and sda6? if the iso is equal or greater in size your data is most likely overwritten, and thus gone.

Comment: the size of sda6 is 195 GB while that of the iso is 1 GB, do you know a solution to recover the file ?

Comment: yes. I have done this before (I also `dd` a USB stick on top of my hard drive). In my case I had a single partition with a ext4 filesystem. I answered my own question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46914/recovering-ext4-partition-after-dding-over-start-of-hd/49574#49574)

Comment: in fact, there is another error i did made after, running mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda6, will that still work ?